# justify content between doesnt work in parent flex

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, flexbox

I add `div` using `flex` display parent of `flex` display.

HTML:

```
<div class="d-flex align-items-start flex-column" style="height: 100px;">
  start
</div>
<div class="d-flex align-items-end flex-column" style="height: 100px;">
  <div class="d-flex justify-content-between align-content-center">
    <div>
      left
    </div>
    <div>
      right
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

in action I need to show two `div` in `left` and `right` so add `justify-content-between` class but this this class doesnt work and not show in left and right. how do fix this problem ?!

demo [here](https://jsfiddle.net/r547cmfv/)

Comment: just remove align-items-end from parent child [https://jsfiddle.net/qLmg4wc8/](https://jsfiddle.net/qLmg4wc8/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to remove "align-items-end" from the parent div of "left and right" then it will work.

**EDITED**:

The explanation for that is if you are using d-flex on a parent div along with "align-items-end" then what will happen is that the parent div will align all the items to the parent div's flex's end so in this case the items inside of the parent div were aligned to the parent div's flex's "end" and "justify-content-between" wasn't working coz the items were stuck at the parent div "flex's" end. Hope this helps. Thanks.

Comment: this is more a comment than an answer

Comment: I know and I can't add comments to a question as I don't have 50 reputation.

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it

Answer (score -1):

```
<div class="d-flex align-items-start flex-column" style="height: 100px;">
  start
</div>
<div class="d-flex justify-content-between align-content-center" style="height: 100px;">
  <div>
    left
  </div>
  <div>
    right
  </div>
 </div>
```